# С++ заполнение поля класса в компил-тайме

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Хотелось бы получить возможность заполнять байтовое поле в классе гарантировано в компил-тайме используя человекочитаемые enum'ы и структуры.
Например:

```
myStruct one
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint8_t b;
}
class Descriptor:
{
    uint8_t fld[];
    Descriptor(myStruct one, int two, char *three);
}
Descriptor({0xEF10,0x12},2,"ABC"}) //forms 0xEF101202414243
```

Как это сделать? В шаблоны не передать структуры, из констекспра не вернуть константный массив.

Comment: Запись `uint8_t fld[];`  невалидна в с++. Размер массива должен быть указан. Чтобы гарантировано инициализировать поле класса к compile-time необходимо объявить `constexpr` конструктор и создать `constexpr` экземпляр такого класса. *"В шаблоны не передать структуры, из констекспра не вернуть константный массив."* - оба утверждения не соответствуют действительности.

Comment: Судя по вашему примеру, это будет что-то очень особенное... У одних нужно менять порядок байт, у других нет, у `int` надо обрезать нулевые байты, у `char*` - выбрасывать завершающий нулевой символ... Стоит ли ваша овчинка такой сложной выделки?: вы же сами запутаетесь...

Comment: Да, uint8_t fld[]; я написал для упрощения. Хотелось бы вычислять его в компил-тайме. Constexpr является слабым типизатором, и не гарантирует создания всего в компил-тайме. Шаблоны нельзя специализировать структурами.

Comment: Это сборка дескриптора USB устройства. Если делать это по-другому, то запутаться ещё проще.

Comment: Что это за термин "типпизатор"? И нет, constexpr гарантирует проведение операции именно в compile time. А шаблоны можно специализировать структурами.

Comment: Про то, как компилятор забивает на constexpr и генерирует функцию при явном указании константных аргументов полно историй из интернета. А как шаблоны можно специализировать структурами (без указателей?)

Comment: *"полно историй из интернета"* - если у вас нет [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), то грош цена этим историям. В качестве параметра шаблона можно использовать ссылки, а в С++20 можно использовать структуры с передачей по значению. Только непонятно, что вы  привязались к структурам, если собираетесь инициализировать массив `uint8_t`.

Comment: Массив uint8_t нужен для дальнейшей отправки и для того, чтобы избежать использования компилятор-специфичных уловок с выравниванием байтов в структуре. А структуры удобны тем, что позволяют связывать логически связанные параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Может что-то типа такого:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <int v1, int v2> class descr{

    int val1=v1;
    int val2=v2;

    public:

    void print(){
        std::cout<<std::endl<< "val1="<<val1;
        std::cout<<std::endl<< "val2="<<val2;
        }

    };


int main()
{

  descr<1,2> descr1;
  descr<2,3> descr2;

  descr1.print();
  descr2.print();

return 0;  
}
```

Проверялось на cpp.sh

Вывод программы:

```
val1=1
val2=2
val1=2
val2=3
```

Comment: Вообще я с этого начал, но тут при специализации не хватает структур. Говорят, что можно только integral type

Comment: Сейчас попробую со структурами. Думаю, что можно и со структурами. Но и с интегральными типами можно. Просто надо поля структур присвоить интегральным типам.

Comment: @Goron Dekar Да, со структурами просто не получается, все через одно место. Тогда через интегральные типы и передавать их прямо в структуры из параметров шаблона. А чем плохо? Вполне себе юзабельно.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

struct myStruct
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint8_t b;
};

class Descriptor
{
    public: uint8_t fld[2 + 1 + 4 + 4];

    public: constexpr
    Descriptor
    (
        myStruct one
    ,   int two
    ,   char const ( & three )[4]
    ) noexcept
    :   fld
        {
            static_cast<uint8_t>((one.a >> 0u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>((one.a >> 8u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>(one.b)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>((two >>  0u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>((two >>  8u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>((two >> 16u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>((two >> 24u) bitand 0xFFu)
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>(three[0])
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>(three[1])
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>(three[2])
        ,   static_cast<uint8_t>(three[3])
        }
    {
        return;
    }
};

constexpr Descriptor desc{{0xEF10,0x12}, 2, "ABC"}; // инициализация во время компиляции
static_assert(desc.fld[0] == 0x10); // проверка корректности инициализации во время компиляции
static_assert(desc.fld[1] == 0xEF);
static_assert(desc.fld[2] == 0x12);
// ...

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/EcjM5I)

Comment: Тут не хватает переменной длины three. Но идея хороша.

Comment: @GoronDekar Если длина нужна переменная, то можно вынести ее в качестве параметра шаблона чтобы она выводилась из аргумента.

Comment: Там не строка будет, а вектор структур :(

Comment: @GoronDekar Уважаемый, ответ относится к фрагменту кода, приведенному в вопросе. Вектор структур во время компиляции использовать не получится.